# Linq expression to fill model containing other List<T>

Tags: c#, linq

I have a model (sample below), and sample data with desired output..
I have also given two ways to populate model which will give desired output but for somereason, 
looks like I am missing something....

Not able to figure out what is the issue here...

need inputs in correcting approach 1 or approach 2 or you can also suggest any other approach which will help populate model in below response..

models

```
class Emp
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public int Name {get;set;}
  public List<cardType> cardTypes {get;set;}

}

class cardType
{
  public int name {get;set;}
  public DateTime Expiry {get;set;}

}


sample data (Data is returned in 1 table only)
id  Name    cardTypeName    exp
1   a       Amex             1010
1   a        City             2010

desired output
<Emp>
  <ID>1</id>
  <name>1</name>
  <cardTypes>
    <cardType>
            <Name> Amex </Name>
            <exp>  1010  </exp>
    </cardType>
    <cardType>
            <Name> City </Name>
            <exp>  2010  </exp>
    </cardType>
  <cardTypes>
</Emp>
```

approach 1

```
(dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                     .GroupBy(r => r.ItemArray[1])
                     .Select(grp => new Emp()
                     {
                            id = r.itemarray[1],
                            name = r.itemarray[1],
                        cardTypes = grp.Select(t => new cardType()
                         {
                            field 1,
                            field 2    
                         }).ToList()
                     }));
```

approach 2

```
 return (from DataRow dr in dataTable.Rows
                        select new Emp
                        {
                            id = "",
                            name= "",
                             cardTypes = dataTable.AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(x => new cardType
                                {
                                   name = ""
                                   exp = ""

                                }).ToList(),
                        });
```

Comment: I believe, in both instances, you're missing a .ToList() in the outer expression.

Comment: @ChrisDixon, Since my outer layer is not of type List... so did not put .ToList() and also I tried once to check if that is issue... but no luck

Comment: Do you need the output as xml or do you just want to get the data into the model?

Comment: And your Expiry field is DateTime, but actual data contains just year. maybe change to int? if not, then which date 2010 mean? 01/01/2010 ? 31/12/2010?

Comment: @OfirWinegarten - I have to populate the model... xml is just a sample I gave..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
return dataTable.AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
            .Select(x => new
            {
                id = x.Key,
                name = x.Key,
                cardTypes = x.Select(t => new
                {
                    name = t.Name,
                    exp = t.Exp
                })
            });
```

Comment: If I use exact type i.e. instead of var and if I put Emp - it gives error..  and if I change return type to IEnumerable<Emp> ... it works... but this is not what need.... I need the return type to be Emp only.. private Emp GetEmp(Datatable dt)

Comment: I got it now... changed the .Select to SingleOrDefault and removed x=> because need emp info only once... and able to return the type as EMP

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you considering you will change the `Expiry` field in `cardType` to `int`

```
var results =
    dt.AsEnumerable()
        .GroupBy(row => row.ItemArray[0])
        .Select(rows => new Emp
        {
            id = rows.Key,
            name = rows.Key,
            cardTypes = rows.Select(row => new cardType {Name = row.ItemArray[2], Expiry = row.ItemArray[3]})
        });
```

If you desire to have `DateTime`, then decide how to convert. For example:

```
cardTypes = rows.Select(row => new cardType {Name = row.ItemArray[2], Expiry = new DateTime(row.ItemArray[3],1,1)})
```

Comment: If I use exact type i.e. instead of var and if I put Emp - it gives error..  and if I change return type to IEnumerable<Emp> ... it works... but this is not what need.... I need the return type to be Emp only.. private Emp GetEmp(Datatable dt)

Comment: got it now... changed the .Select to SingleOrDefault and removed x=> because need emp info only once... and able to return the type as EMP... testing now...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize to xml your models, you should mark your models with `[Serializable]` attribute and just use `XmlSerializer`.

```
[Serializable]
class Emp
{
  public int id {get;set;}
  public int Name {get;set;}
  public List<cardType> cardTypes {get;set;}

}
[Serializable]
class cardType
{
  public int name {get;set;}
  public DateTime Expiry {get;set;}

}
```

After that you can use following code:

```
static Dictionary<int, Emp> ConvertToDict(DataTable dt)
    {
        Dictionary<int, Emp> emps = new Dictionary<int, Emp>();
        foreach (var dr in dt.AsEnumerable())
        {
            var id = (int)dr["ID"];
            var name = (string)dr["Name"];
            var cardTypeName = (string)dr["CardTypeName"];
            var exp = (int)dr["Exp"];
            Emp emp;
            var cardType = new CardType { Name = cardTypeName, Exp = exp };
            if (emps.TryGetValue(id, out emp))
            {
                emp.CardTypes.Add(cardType);
            }
            else
            {
                emps.Add(id, new Emp { ID = id, Name = name, CardTypes = new List<CardType> { cardType } });
            }
        }
        return emps;
    }

    static List<string> Serialize<T>(IEnumerable<T> entities) where T:new()
    {
        var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

        var serializedEntities = entities.Select(entity =>
        {
            using (var sw = new StringWriter())
            {
                ser.Serialize(sw, entity);
                return sw.ToString();
            }
        }).ToList();
        return serializedEntities;
    }
```